# Sum of the digits

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

Let $N$ be the greatest number that will divide $1305,4665$ and $6905$, leaving the same remainder in each case. Then what is the sum of the digits in $N$?

Comment: Definitely I have tried and then asked.... I have tried by assuming and then taking H.C.F.

Answer (score 2):

Since division by $N$ leaves the same remainder for all three numbers, $N$ leaves zero remainder when divided into the difference of each pair.

Answer (score 2):

$4665-1305=3360$ so the numbers need to divide $3360$
$6905-4665=2240$ so the numbers need to divide $2240$
The numbers need to divide $1120=2^5\cdot5\cdot7$
Knowing the prime factorization of a number, you can find the sum of all the factors of that number.

**Hint 1:** The sum of the factors of $p^n$ is
$$
1+p+p^2+p^3+\dots+p^n=\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}
$$
**Hint 2:** We can find all the factors of $p^3q^2$ in the product
$$
(1+p+p^2+p^3)(1+q+q^2)
$$

Comment: Thank you.... My approach was same but I couldn't reach the answer

Comment: @harspt92: I have added a couple of hints that should finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: One way to think of $a$ and $b$ as leaving the same remainder upon division by $m$ is $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$

Comment: That's not what we have here. We have $N \pmod a = N \pmod b$.

Comment: @TonyK:  I took the problem to mean dividing the three given numbers by $N$ and getting the same remainder in each case.  The $m$ in my answer corresponds to $N$ in the original problem.